# Why we should have an ID column in the table of users?

Tags: mysql, database

It's obvious that we already have another unique information about each user, and that is username. Then, why we need another unique thing for each user? Why should we also have an id for each user? What would happen if we omit the id column?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even if your username is unique, there are few advantages to having an extra id column instead of using the varchar as your primary key.

- Some people prefer to use an integer column as the primary key, to serve as a surrogate key that never needs to change, even if other columns are subject to change.  Although there's nothing preventing a natural primary key from being changeable too, you'd have to use cascading foreign key constraints to ensure that the foreign keys in related tables are updated in sync with any such change.
- The primary key being a 32-bit integer instead of a varchar can save space.  The choice between a int or a varchar foreign key column in every other table that references your user table can be a good reason.
- Inserting to the primary key index is a little bit more efficient if you add new rows to the end of the index, compared to of wedging them into the middle of the index.  Indexes in MySQL tables are usually B+Tree data structures, and you can study these to understand how they perform.
- Some application frameworks prefer the convention that every table in your database has a primary key column called `id`, instead of using natural keys or compound keys.  Following such conventions can make certain programming tasks simpler.

None of these issues are deal-breakers.  And there are also advantages to using natural keys:

- If you look up rows by username more often than you search by id, it can be better to choose the username as the primary key, and take advantage of the index-organized storage of InnoDB.  Make your primary lookup column be the primary key, if possible, because primary key lookups are more efficient in InnoDB (you should be using InnoDB in MySQL).
- As you noticed, if you already have a unique constraint on username, it seems a waste of storage to keep an extra id column you don't need.
- Using a natural key means that foreign keys contain a human-readable value, instead of an arbitrary integer id.  This allows queries to use the foreign key value without having to join back to the parent table for the "real" value.

The point is that there's no rule that covers 100% of cases.  I often recommend that you should keep your options open, and use natural keys, compound keys, and surrogate keys even in a single database.

I cover some issues of surrogate keys in the chapter "ID Required" in my book [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).

Comment: *The primary key being a 32-bit integer instead of a varchar can save space* I don't really buy into this. Long before this would become an issue you'd run into other scalability problems. However the fact that frameworks assume PKs are going to be integers is an excellent point

Comment: @ConradFrix, the storage difference can be a little or a lot, depending on the length of the strings.  Also think not only of the storage for a few thousand rows in the PK, but for hundreds of millions of rows in foreign key columns in referencing tables.  It adds up.

Answer (score 8):

This identifier is known as a [Surrogate Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key).  The page I linked lists both the advantages and disadvantages.

In practice, I have found them to be advantageous because even superkey data can change over time (i.e. a user's email address may change and thus any corresponding relations *must* change), but a surrogate key never needs to change for the data it identifies because its value is meaningless to the relation.

It's also nice from a `JOIN` standpoint because it can be an integer with a smaller key length than a varchar.

I can say that in practice I prefer to use them.  I have been bitten too many times by having multiple-column primary keys or a data-representative superkey used across tables having to become non-unique later due to changing requirements during development, and that is not a situation you want to deal with.

Comment: +1. This is a really good answer. You don't really need an surrogate primary key (with all its desirable aspects: simple, immutable, unique, anonymous, etc.), until you find you do need one, because it turns out that the "candidate key" previously elected as the primary key turns out to be missing one of those really important aspects of  a primary key (when it turns out that selected primary key is not really unique, or it's not really immutable, or it's not really anonymous... the inordinate time and effort for making changes to accommodate that, and downstream systems that are impacted...

Comment: "In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice, there is."  -- unknown

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, every table should have a unique, auto-incremented id.

Here are some practical reasons.  If you have duplicate rows, you can readily determine which row to delete.  If you want to know the order that rows were inserted, you have that information in the id.  As for users, there's more than on "John Smith" in the world.  An id provides a key for foreign references.

Finally, just about anything that might describe a user -- a name, an address, a telephone number, an email address -- could change over time.

Answer (score 3):

im mysql we have.

```
 1:Index fields 2:Unique fields and 3:PK fields.
index means pointable
unique means in a table must be one in all rows.
PK = index + unique
```

in a table you may have lots of unique fields like
 username or passport code or email.
but you need a field like ID. that is both unique and index (=PK).which is first is always one thing and never changes and second is unique and third is simple (because is often number).

Answer (score 2):

One reason to have a numeric id is that creating an index on it is leaner than on a text-field, reducing index size and processing time required to look up a specific user. Also it's less bytes to save when cross-referencing to a user (relational database) in a different table.