# How to append text(query) to a react-router URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

[image: example]
In the attachment, it's clear that the question is fetched using the id `15777142` from the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777142/why-we-should-have-an-id-column-in-the-table-of-users` and then question text (as query) is appended to the URL. The text after `15777142` has no meaning independently.
Can we achieve the same using react-router-5?

How I am handling it as of now:

```
<Route path="/questions/:id/:title" component={Question}/>

<Link to="/questions/15777142/my-xyz-text">Go to question</Link>
```

It does return the page for me but if the user deletes the text from URL, it still returns the same page but doesn't append the text at the end. I am fetching the details using `:id` on `componentDidMount()`

I have no idea how to convert it to meet my requirement.

Kindly help me with achieving this. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea here is not to rely on the user to provide the text at all, this might be malformed or missing characters at any time. Instead you can fill in the text that you receive from the API or any other source.

This can be done as simple as:

```
export default ({ match }) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = match.params.id;
    const item = data.find(item => item.id === id);
    setItem(item);
  }, []);
  if(!item) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <section>
      <Redirect to={`/answer/${item.id}/${item.text}`} />
      <p>Answer</p>
    </section>
  )
}
```

with Route being defined as:

```
<Route path="/answer/:id" component={Answer} />
```

`Redirect` offers two advantages here:

1. the component is not rerendered because the `Route` leading to it is one and the same.
2. it uses `replace` instead of `push` meaning that the redirection will not be part of the history stack of user. (user cannot press back and go back to the page with no text)

Comment: Can you please provide an example without hooks as well?

Comment: @TheCoder The hooks are simply fetching the required item with `id` that is received from the URL, without hooks that logic would go into `componentDidMount` or wherever you are fetching the data

Comment: And the above code is the `Answer` component, right?

Comment: yes, the component with is added to the route so that it gets match props

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const Answer =  ({ match }) => { }; export default Answer;` ?

Comment: you can choose to name it or not, depends on your preference. you don't _have_ to name your default export